# send checkbox values to php through ajax results in null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the values of 7 jquery checkboxes to php via ajax. I am attempting to put the values in an array and serialize the array in ajax. Ultimately, I would like to use the values of the checkboxes as conditions in a MySQL WHERE clause. My ajax completes successfully but the value of the array is always null no matter what method I try using.

CODE: ***note: I've updated the code on here to reflect the suggested edits provided in the answers.***

My HTML code:

```
<label for="prestage_select">Prestage</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="prestage_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Prestage">


<label for="validation_select">Validation</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="validation_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Validation"> 


<label for="scheduling_select">Scheduling</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="scheduling_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Scheduling">


<label for="production_select">Production</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="production_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Production">


<label for="needsBOL_select">Needs BOL</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="needsBOL_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Needs BOL">


<label for="shpAcct2Close_select">Shipped: Account to Close</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="shpAcct2Close_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Shipped: Acctg. To Close Out">


<label for="movedToComplete_select">Moved to Complete for Selected Period</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="movedToComplete_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Complete">
```

My Ajax Code:

```
j("#create_submit").click(function(){

    //send Revenue Data values to php using ajax.
                  var revenuechbxarray = j('.revenuechbxs:checked').val();
                  var revenuefrom = j('#revenuefrom').val();
                  var revenueto = j('#revenueto').val();

                  j.ajax ({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: "revenue_report.php",
                      data: { revenuefromtext: revenuefrom, revenuetotext: revenueto, revenuechbx: revenuechbxarray },
                      success: function( response ) {
                          j('#fieldset_ReportDiv').html(response);
                          }
                  });

             console.log(revenuechbxarray);
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php

include('inc.php');


//Get date range.

$revenuefromajax=$_POST['revenuefromtext'];
$revenuetoajax=$_POST['revenuetotext'];

$revenuefromstring = strtotime($revenuefromajax);
$revenuetostring = strtotime($revenuetoajax);

$revenuefrom=date("Y-m-d", $revenuefromstring);
$revenueto=date("Y-m-d", $revenuetostring);


//Get selected Status Values.

$revenue_check = $_POST['revenuechbx']; //
print_r($revenue_check); //displays result of one checkbox (the first selected on) but not more than one...


//connect  to the database 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//echo 'MySQL Connected successfully.'."<BR>";


$conn->select_db("some database name");  /////Database name has been changed for security reasons/////////

if(! $conn->select_db("some database name") ) {
    echo 'Could not select database. '."<BR>";
}

// echo 'Successfully selected database. '."<BR>";

//Select Data and Display it in a table.


$sql = "SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, invoices.stagestatus, FORMAT(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice), 2) AS totalprice, clients.company, lineitems.invoiceid, FORMAT((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144, 2 ) AS sqft, lineitems.quantity AS qty, FORMAT((invoices.totalprice / ((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144)), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice) / lineitems.quantity), 2) AS avgunitrevenue
    FROM clients
    INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.clientid
    INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid
    WHERE invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."'
    ORDER BY invoices.id DESC";


$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
<tr>

<th>Customer</th>
<th>SG</th>
<th>Revenue</th>
<th>SQ FT</th>
<th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
<th>Number of Units</th>
<th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
</tr>";


 if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

     // fetch associative array 
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['sqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     } 

     echo "</table>";

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     //Free the result variable. 
     $result->free();
}

//Close the Database connection.
$conn->close(); 


?>
```

I have tried several different suggestions for sending the values to php but the value is always null.

Note: I included the other ajax call for revenueto and revenuefrom date. This call is successful and my table displays correctly based off those dates. I just can't seem the get actual values for my selected checkboxes from the same page as the dates.

Comment: Can you log serialized string `revenuechbxarray`?

Comment: I see 2 ajax calls, the first one where you send your checkboxes data doesnt have a success function

Answer (score 2):

You are using a class selector while your checkboxes does not have class attributes

Answer (score 0):

some changes in your code step by step

> html code

```
 <input class="revenue" type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="production_select" value="Production">
```

set checkbox name array and add common class revenue add and selecter user by javascript code

> Ajax code

```
var revenuechbxarray = $('.revenue:checked').val();
```

> PHP code:

```
$revenue_check = $_POST['revenuechbx']; // this is array
```

you can user this array json_encode to convert json string and set database.

Comment: thank you! I am able to see the value of my first checkbox in console.log() now. However, I can't see other checkboxes. Just one. Will json_encode allow me to get and use the values of each checkbox my my MySQL code? If so, can you give an example of json_encode?

Answer (score 0):

To select the checkboxes by name:

```
j('[name=revenue_checkboxes]:checked').serialize()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.